# JPA MappedSuperClass Inheritence Strategy

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

Is `@Inheritance`,`@DiscriminatorValue`,`@DiscriminatorColumn` applicable to `@MappedSuperClass` ?

---

Question is asked because In **ORM.XML JPA Specification** Entity have attribute :

```
     "inheritance",
    "discriminatorValue",
    "discriminatorColumn",
```

but MappedSuperclass does not have .

Comment: How about some example code to clarify the context? Pretty wide open otherwise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're not applicable. `MappedSuperclass` is used for code reuse, and not for entity inheritance. It's only used to share common properties and methods between entities that have, otherwise, nothing in common.